# Recreating a varbinary hex string in AWS Redshift via Python UDF

Tags: python, hex, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL Server database where uniqueidentifiers are converted and stored as varbinary(8) i.e.

```
DECLARE @OrganisationID uniqueidentifier = '910D514A-8706-4BA1-9327-FE92EF4165E3';
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(8), @OrganisationID, 1); /* 0x4A510D910687A14B */
```

I now need to recreate these hexadecimal representations of uniqueidentifiers within an AWS Redshift database.

There is no equivalent to the varbinary type in redshift so I believe the only way I could do this woulbe be via a python UDF?  I've managed to create a UDF which takes a string, converts that string into bytes, and from there creates a hex string. However I can't get them to match up. Is there a way I can format the hex string generated by my python below to match the SQL varbinary 0x4A510D910687A14B?

```
create or replace function hex(data character varying)
returns character varying
as $$
import binascii
s = data.encode("utf-8")
s = binascii.hexlify(s)
return s
$$ language plpythonu stable;
select hex('910D514A-8706-4BA1-9327-FE92EF4165E3');
/* 39313044353134412d383730362d344241312d393332372d464539324546343136354533 */
```